# Capture value from the JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to call an API and getting the results back in the form of JSON. I need to parse the data received and collect the specific data "key" under mapping in below mentioned JSON data from the array. I also want to get the total count of key under the mapping, so that I can recurse the array and retrieve the key.

JSON data as below,

```
{
    "$type": "Type1",
    "mapping": [
        {
            "value": "Value1",
            "key": "Key1"
        },
        {
            "value": "Value2",
            "key": "Key2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am stuck in the code until below mentioned. Was not sure how to proceed further. Kindly suggest how can I get the value

```
using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       text = sr.ReadToEnd();
       dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
       //Need suggestion how can I retrieve the specific
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should deserialize to classes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick Console app that does what you are trying to do.  The trick is to traverse the dynamic object until you find what you want.  But cast everything as `dynamic` as you go.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = "{ \"$type\": \"Type1\",\"mapping\": [ { \"value\": \"Value1\", \"key\": \"Key1\" }, { \"value\": \"Value2\", \"key\": \"Key2\" } ] }";

        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
        dynamic mapping = result.mapping;
        foreach(dynamic item in mapping as IEnumerable<dynamic>)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", (string)item.value, (string)item.key);
        }
        var done = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: glad it worked. `dynamic` is pretty useful when you're working with JSON.